# Negative number in a formula for google spreadsheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Issue with a negative number (-10%) in the formula =IF(AND($B1>-10%),2,)
It works fine if the number is positive. Tried to put (-) in parenthesis, but it did not work out.

Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JBpX4u4tIhOf1jAQrlqXPf8smGB7gP4mmZldmm60SBQ/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: it is a part of a complex formula which includes negative and positive numbers: =IF(AND($B6>-10%),2,AND($B6>10%),3,)

Comment: see your sheet if this helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pikkf.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(B1>-10%, 2, )
```

so if B1 is -9% or 5% or 20% it will output `2`

if B1 will be -11% or -50% or -18% it will output empty cell due to 2nd parameter of `IF` being empty